# Check IS JSON/IS NOT JSON in Hibernate QL

Tags: json, oracle, hibernate, plsql

In oracle it is a valid query to check `IS JSON` for example

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE address IS JSON`

Is there a way to send this query to an oracle database using hibernate without creating a native query?